# Making a process wait for command

Tags: python, unix, process

I'm making a program which executes commands I type in to linux. For instance:

~> Python myProgram start
~> cd Music (or some other linux command)
~/Music> Python myProgram doSomething
~/Music> cd ..
~>Python myProgram doSomethingElse

I guess the program must look something like this:

```
if sys.argv == "start":
  get processID
  echo processID >> /dev/shm/ID
  while True:
    wait for command
    method(argument)
if sys.argv == "doSomething":
  processID = read("/dev/shm/ID")
  tell process to run method(doSomething)

def Method()
def read()
```

My question is: Where do I start? Do I have to use Thread, Multiprocessing, Subprocess or Popen?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what is `def Method()` and `def read()`?

Comment: To me it looks like you need `subprocess` although I don't understand your use-case for replacing a terminal... There are probably fancier ways using `readline` or `pexpect`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a near interface for creating command line tools with python, this may be a good point to start https://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html